# Pl sql invocation using pre sql in IICS

Tags: sql, oracle, cloud, informatica

I have a pl Sql script which I need to run through IICs (informatica cloud).Is it possible to call pl sql script in pre sql and send input parameters as mapping parameters.

Note : i don’t have sql transformation licence so have to use pre sql functionality

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Are there any issues you're facing?

Comment: You can check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyjiIoJ8gnY and https://network.informatica.com/thread/85056

Comment: I am able to call the stores procedure in pre sql but unable to pass parameters. 
If I pass parameters IICS is using parameter name in the query instead of its value.

Comment: Ok, did you try enclosing the parameter with single quote? Or vice versa. But i think, its better to store the output in some stg table and use the table as source. Because i don't think passing it through parameter will work